# Javascript print square using for loop and conditional statement only

Tags: javascript, for-loop, conditional-statements

Just started my uni course, struggling a little with javascript. I have been asked to display a square using any character, however, the solution must combine for loops and if statements.

This is what I have so far and I feel pretty close but I just can't get the second line to display. I know this can be done via two for loops, (one for iteration of the variable and another for spaces). But this is not how I have been asked to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
var size = 3;
let i;


for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
print ("*");
if (size === i){ 
println (""); 
}
}
```

For context, this is all taking place int he professors homemade learning environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use nested `for` loops and take a line break after each filled line.

```js
function print(s) { document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += s; }
function println(s) { document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += s + '\n'; }

var size = 5,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        print("*");
    }
    println("");
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Single loop with a check if `i` is unequal to zero and if the remainder is zero, then add a line break.

Using:

- [`===` identity/strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) operator checks the type and the value, for example if both are numbers and if the value is the same,
- [`!==` non-identity/strict inequality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Non-identity_strict_inequality_(!)) operator it is like above, but it checks the oposite of it,
- [`%` remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator, which returns a rest of a number which division returns an integer number.
- [`&&` logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) operator, which check both sides and returns the last value if both a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (like any array, object, number not zero, a not empty string, `true`), or the first, if it is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (like `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `''` (empty string), `false`, the oposite of truthy).

```js
function print(s) { document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += s; }
function println(s) { document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += s + '\n'; }

var size = 5,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    if (i !== 0 && i % size === 0) {
        println("");
    }
    print("*");
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: This is confusing me a little lol, also, the output for instance would need to appear like a filled in square not an empty one. Thankyou though.

Comment: sorry, now with filled output.

Comment: This is how I have done it before, however, he now wants a conditional statement to be in there. This was my first suggestion but he said I was not playing the game fair lol.

Comment: Some of those conditional operations are lost on me, any chance of some annotation to explain what the modulus function is doing?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I really like the way this one works, I should have thought about the problem a bit more before typing anything. I had not even considered checking the remainder of from i to create a new line. My think was much more linear.

Answer (score 0):

Well the for loop is only iterating 3 times, printing the first line. If you want a square you'll have to print 9 stars total, right? So i'm assuming, is this is the approach you'd go for, you would need to iterate not until `size`, but until `size * size`.

Comment: The loop needs to actually capture the user input of the number of *'s which make up the square. if I was to iterate on size * size would I not just end up with a string of 9 *'s though? - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You wanna make a square of * where the size is the number of * on its sides?

Let's split a task into 3 parts:

- where you print top side like *****
- where you print middle (left and right sides) like *    *
- where you print bottom (same as top)

Now let's code that, I kept the code as simple as possible, this can be done in fewer lines but I think this will be easier to understand for beginners:

```
var size = 5;
var i = 0;

// top
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    console.log("*");

//middle
for (var j = 0; j < size - 2; j++){
  console.log("\n"); // go to next row
  // middle (2 on sides with size-2 in between)
  console.log("*");
  for (i = 0; i < size-2; i++)
    console.log(" ");
  console.log("*\n"); // goes to new row as well
}

// same as top
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    console.log("*");
```

Full square is even simpler:

```
var size = 5;
var i = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++){ // iterates rows
  for (var j = 0; j < size; j++) // iterates * in row
      console.log("*");
  console.log("\n") // moves to new row
}
```

In order to print a row, you print same sign X times. Well, to print X rows we can use just that 1 more time (only this time we are iterating over a different variable (j is * in a row, i is a number of rows).

After a row is made we go to go to next row with \n.

As for

> it must contain if statement

Put this at the end:

```
if (youCanHandleTheTruth) console.log("It's a terrible practice to tell students their solution MUST CONTAIN CODEWORDS. If you need them to showcase something, write appropriate task that will require them to do so.");
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful however the square does not need to be empty, its needs to be s static X*X squares with a character in each.

Comment: Just a reminder it must contain at least one if statement.

Comment: Tell to whoever gave you a task that conditioning the solution to contain codewords is terrible. It's not in the spirit of programming. But, fine, you can always add an if in the end ;) If you wanna it showed just initialize youCanHandleTheTruth to truthy value :D

Comment: Hahah i'm sure he will be over the moon with that feed back!

I took a break and I have come back to this, which is giving the correct display for the first line at least. I thought about putting an else in but I just can't figure out how I would get it scale effectively without lines and lines of nested ifs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using console.log to 'print' the square:

```
    var dimension = 10;
    var edge = '*';
    var inside = ' ';
    var printLine;

    for (var i = 1; i <= dimension; i++) {
        if (i === 1 || i === dimension) {
            printline = Array(dimension + 1).join(edge);
        } else {
            printline = edge + Array(dimension - 1).join(inside) + edge;
        }
        console.log(printline);
    }
```

Note that in the following example, an array of length 11 gets you only 10 "a"s, since Array.join puts the argument between the array elements:

```
Array(11).join('a'); // create string with 10 as "aaaaaaaaaa"
```

Comment: Nice thinking with Array.join().