# How to make Square Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make Square Number like this one:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

i want to make it with function:

```
function drawSquareBox(num) {


};

drawSquareBox(3);
```

if i make `drawSquareBox(3)` the output is:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

another example, if i make `drawSquareBox(5)`, the output is

1  2  3  4  5

6  7  8  9  10

11 12 13 14 15

16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25

What should i do? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a place to ask more specific questions, and one of the important rules to to show us what you have tried, the current output, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: This is the closest dupe I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727814/javascript-print-square-using-for-loop-and-conditional-statement-only. Not marking it as its not exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im assuming you want console log output to be in that format. Below is my approach,  hope it helps.

```js
function drawSquareBox(num) {
  const number = new Array(num).fill().map((_, outer) => {
    const innerArr = new Array(num)
      .fill()
      .map((_, inner) => inner + 1 + num * outer);
    return innerArr.join(" ");
  });
  const res = number.join("\n");
  console.log(res);
}

drawSquareBox(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let s = 3;
let counter = 1;

for(let i=0; i<s; i++) {
  let temp = [];
  for(let j=0; j<s; j++) {
    temp.push(counter++)
  }  
  console.log(temp.join(' '));
}
```